# Route translate the namespace route of a rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing, rails-engines

I have a rails engine which is mounted on my application as

```
mount Engine::Engine, at: "/engine"
```

Is it possible to translate the namespace `/engine` so that in English it is `/engine` and in another language in my routes it is `/injin`

so in my routes.rb, i am hoping for something like this

I tried this in my main application

```
en:
  routes:
    engine: "engine"

ms:
  routes:
    engine: "injin"
```

But it is not working because obviously, it is a namespaced route so not sure how to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can take a chance with [RouteTranslator](https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator) gem.
See gem issues #173 and #178 though.